# pass AngularJS object value from ng-repeat to AngularJS function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller

I am trying desperately to pass a Angular object value onto a function. The various attempts have resulted in no progress, and the only time I got it to work properly when I hard code the values.

The MVC View:

```
<tr ng-repeat="project in projects | filter:search:strict">
<td><span><a style="cursor:default" title="Ändra i projektet.." id="{{project.id}}" data-ng-click="opents('/EditProject/', '{{ project.id }}')">{{ project.id }}</a></span></td>
```

The Angular function:

```
$scope.opents = function (tsUrl, id) {
        alert('/EditProject/'+ $attrs);
        alert(tsUrl);
        alert(id);
        alert(tsUrl + id);
        TINY.box.show({ url: tsUrl + id });
    };
```

I've tried to recieve different values from the invoke in the view, hence the many alerts. Can't find a solution for this from the web and hope someone knows of a solution.

Comment: You can not set any JS code in your ng-click. Typically "alert" does not work. It is a specific JS minimalist processor served by Angular. The angular way is to embed Jquery or any external code in a directive. Otherwise is it not taken into account during the angular digest, and your ng-repeat is not aware of you DOM changes outside of a directive...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
ng-click="opents('/EditProject/', project.id)"
```

Comment: Please help to understand me what do you mean :)
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick

Comment: I just now used a HttpUtility to pass {{ project.id }} to get the proper convertion when invoking the function. So it gets it into a javascript string.
Now the problem is the function itself is not receiving that value but instead the text {{ project.id}}, so problem remains... :-)

Comment: project.id should be passed to opents without quites and without {{ symbols. Can you update the code?

Comment: that unfortunately doesnt. If you saw my previously answer I checked the wrong property...sorry :-)

Comment: Thing is, that contents of ng-click="..." is being evaluated as usual Javascript, no additional {{, neither encoding needed. And "project" variable also acts as usual JS variable.

Just update the code to see why it's not working :) Or even better try using JSFiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Got it functional with using $event when invoking the function...problem solved.

Comment: And I got i functional when i used what you suggested later... thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

From the view I used $event instead.

```
ng-click="opents('/PopUp2/EditProject/', $event)
```

and in the function:

```
$scope.opents = function (tsUrl, e) {
        var id = e.currentTarget.innerText;
        TINY.box.show({ url: tsUrl + id });
```

and got a functional respons. Hope this helpt someone else!

Comment: That's a pretty tricky approach. I wonder why does not it work with just ng-click="opents('/PopUp2/EditProject/',project)" and then 
$scope.opents = function(tsUrl,model) {
var id = model.id;
...
?